# Q-rings shifting chain not smoothly hitting the teeth

Tags: shifting, rotor

I bought my bike with Q-rings a while ago. Recently I switched to NoQ rings because I wanted to make a better comparison (hadnt ridden round rings in 2 years).

This weekend i re-mounted the Q-rings but even though my Di2 is shifting properly, I do notice that when going on the big Q-ring, in different crank positions it sometimes takes an extra rotation for the (KMC) chain to really drop into the teeth.

What could cause this? I cant recall it happening before the NoQ mounting.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get the ring in the same place?  Or is it rotated by one or more holes?  Or worse, is it flipped left for right ?

Comment: Both rings are mounted in OCP3 as it was originally. Its hard to google on this because its not easy to describe it in search terms and also on the physics of it (why is a chain running over the teeth and only dropping in the teeth after an extra rotation)

Comment: I've run out of ideas, but suspect "shift ramp positions" might come into the answer.

Comment: Your chain has stretched.

Answer (score 1):

Big ring's height relative to the front derailleur cage should be optimal. With oval (not round) rings, this is impossible to set for the entire ring's rotation. As you probably know, the FD cage height is set with the oval ring in it's highest position (otherwise it would rub when this ring's part comes "along").

In addition to this, oval ring is moving up and down (relative to the FD cage) as it spins - which I suppose doesn't help fast shifting.

Having said that, you should be able to set good shifting even with oval rings, perhaps just a little bit slower than it's the case with (really, completely) round rings.

It is possible that, after riding with proper front shifting, you notice a less-fast front shifting. Unless it takes a whole pedal turn more to shift - in that case there is some problem.

Do check FD height and alignment, movement limit and movement when shifting - is it all correct. New chainrings could be slightly further in, or out for that matter.

Also check chainrings and chain for wear, if you haven't already.